# Not able to unserialize complex Object PHP

Tags: php, cookies, serialization, deserialization

I'm doing something that might be kind of stupid. I'am saving a complex object in a cookie:

```
class CocheDTO
{
    private $marca;
    private $enlace;
    private $modelo;
    private $motor;
    private $combustible;
    private $cc;
//With getters and setters
}
```

I'm using the method `Serialize` to send a cookie with this complex object serialized:

```
 $this->cookiesManager->crearCookie("coche",serialize($coche),30);
```

The problem I'm having is that im not able to 'cast' the serialized cookie to an object cookie back. I've done this with Java but I guess that being a strong typed programming language helps.

This is the way I'm trying to unserialize (Which I know is impossible, but not sure how to 'parse' all the attributes of the class.

```
unserialize($this->cookiesManager->obtenerCookie($nombreCookie));
```

Not sure if I'm able to do this with PHP. I read something about using `__wakeup`, but not sure how to use it or how to access to the serialized data.

---

Currently I'm having this error:

> Catchable fatal error: 
>   Object of class CocheDTO could not be converted to string

I know that this might not make alot of sense because I'm trying to serialize and read it back again in PHP (without using BD) and not using JSON or xml to serialize it and read from js, I just want to serialize and unserialize using PHP methods and only from PHP.

**Result of echo serialize($coche)**

> 1O:8:"CocheDTO":6:{s:15:"CocheDTOmarca";s:4:"SEAT";s:16:"CocheDTOenlace";N;s:16:"CocheDTOmodelo";s:5:"IBIZA";s:15:"CocheDTOmotor";s:4:"4080";s:21:"CocheDTOcombustible";s:8:"gasolina";s:12:"CocheDTOcc";s:3:"110";}

**Result of echo var_dump($coche)**

```
> object(CocheDTO)[4]   private 'marca' => string 'SEAT' (length=4)  
> private 'enlace' => null   private 'modelo' => string 'IBIZA'
> (length=5)   private 'motor' => string '4080' (length=4)   private
> 'combustible' => string 'gasolina' (length=8)   private 'cc' => string
> '110' (length=3)
```

Thanks a lot.